# How to store two equal String or any object (with different references) in a HashMap/HashSet?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, equals, hashset

I have written following code, with two String object, but only one String is added in `HashSet` or `HashMap`:

```
String s1 = new String("Text");
String s2 = "Text";

//checking with Reference equality operator
System.out.println("Does both are same object: " + s1 == s2); 
//not equal two different object of String is created

HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<>();
set.add(s1);
set.add(s2);

for (Iterator<String> iterator = set.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    String strObj = (String) iterator.next();
    System.out.println(strObj);
}
```

The output is:

`Text`

I know adding any object in `HashMap` or `HashSet` depends on `equal()` method: i.e. for both the String

```
s1.equals(s2) //returns true
```

that is why only one String is added in `HashMap` or `HashSet`(which is in the contract), but what is the workaround I wanted to add both the String as they are different object.

`String` is a `final` class so I can not create subclass and override `equals()` and `hashCode()` method to check with reference equality operator and return true or false.

Comment: Note: This same "issue" affects all standard Collections and operations - e.g. List.contains, etc - that use `equals`, so HashMap/HashSet are not special (although they do have a trivial "solution").

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think what you want is the [IdentityHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html). This class compares objects by identity (i.e. using `==`) instead of by equality (i.e. using `equals`).

Since there is no `IdentityHashSet` class, if you want a `Set` with the same characteristics of the `IdentityHashMap` you can just use the [`Collections.newSetFromMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#newSetFromMap%28java.util.Map%29) utility method. This utility method just creates a wrapper around the given `Map` to make it look like a `Set`. For example:

```
Set<String> myIdentitySet = Collections.newSetFromMap(new IdentityHashMap<String,Boolean>());
```

Comment: I was going to suggest implementing a set using `IdentityHashMap` in the background. But why implement when a tool already exists to do it for you?

Comment: @YvesDubois `when a tool already exists to do it for you?` please elaborate

Comment: @YvesDubois - Yeah, there are all sorts of nice utility methods like that on the [`Collections`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) class and other classes in the family ([Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html), [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html), etc).

Comment: @Vishrant I meant the `Collections.newSetFromMap` method. You can simply use this method to wrap a `IdentityHashSet` automatically into a set rather than coding it yourself.